# Word or phrase for someone accepting a story completely & unquestioningly

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests, terminology, vocabulary

If someone accepts a version of a story completely, without questioning any part of it, they ..... what?

I'm looking for a word or a phrase or a more elegant, eloquent way of saying it.

Comment: Are you looking for *gullible*?

Comment: Swallowed it, hook, line, and sinker.

Comment: How abou:t They are *unquestioning*?  They have *unquestioning acceptance*

Answer (score 3):

It's not particularly "elegant" but the term I think of is "[bought it](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/buy_1)" ("buy it").

> 3 [transitive] informal    to believe something that someone tells you, especially when it is not likely to be true:

Note the "informal" on the definition.

*I told him my name was "The Great and Powerful Oz" and he bought it.*

Means that the subject believes that my name is "The Great and Powerful Oz", despite the fact that it's a ridiculous thing to say.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want the phrase *wholesale acceptance*.

For example, one might say or write: "The shooter's wholesale acceptance of white supremacy may have made him an easy recruit for neo-Nazi groups like Stormfront."

**Cambridge Dictionaries Online**

> wholesale *adjective*
>   involving everyone or everything; complete
>   *What the system needs is wholesale reform.*

Comment: Please define your phrase and explain how you thinks it fits the need the OP has. :D

Comment: Yup! brilliant. that was the one that was eluding me thank you!

Comment: Hello, gatehead, and welcome to English Language & Usage. Obviously this answer is the one that the poster was looking for—but for other readers who may visit this site and seek a word with the same meaning, your answer would be more useful if it included a definition of "wholesale acceptance" from a suitable reference work. If you add such a definition (with appropriate citation, I will happily upvote your answer.

Comment: They ... accepted it wholesale.  To fit with the format the OP requested.

Comment: Thanks, Sven and aparente. Just edited my response. Glad it was what you were looking for, laura.

Comment: +1, as promised. I didn't realize that you had updated your answer until I went back over some old comments of mine just now.

Answer (score 1):

The first comment, from tchrist, said it best :

- **Gullible**

Answer (score 1):

If I read your question right, you're looking for an elegant verb, and hopefully you'll allow me to add an adverb.  Here are a few ideas.

**They accepted it without question.**

**They accepted it naively.**  (If you want to be fancy, naïvely, with two dots over the i.)

If you want to stay away from *accept* for some reason:

**They admitted it unreservedly / without hesitation.**

**They granted it unquestioningly.**

**They received it ingenuously.**  (*Ingenuous* means innocent and unsuspecting.)

If you need just a verb, with no adverb,

**They swallowed it.**

This is elegant by virtue of being simple.  It is formal if you omit the *hook, line and sinker* part.  The only possible downside I can see is that it's not one of those fancy words that one might want to use to try to impress.

Answer (score 1):

To indicate that the story was believed in its entirety, you could write that **they accepted the story without reservation**.

If your emphasis is on the failure of the audience to question the story and their *uncritical* acceptance of it, consider discussing the **credulity of the listeners** (the individual listeners are **credulous**).

> Credulity is a state of willingness to believe in one or many people or things in the absence of reasonable proof or knowledge.
>
> Credulity is not simply a belief in something that may be false. The subject of the belief may even be correct, but a credulous person will believe it without good evidence. — [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credulity)

Answer (score 0):

*Trusting*

[(ODO)](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/trusting)

> showing or tending to have a belief in a person's honesty or sincerity; not suspicious.

([Macmillan British Dict.](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/trusting)):

> willing to trust people, especially when it's not a sensible thing to do

Answer (score 0):

I would say **gullible**, but there are some great synonyms on [thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/gullible):

> being a sucker, believing, biting, credulous, easily taken in, easy
>   mark, falling hook line and sinker, foolish, green*, innocent, kidding
>   oneself, mark*, silly, simple, sucker, susceptible, swallowing whole,
>   taken in, taking the bait, trustful, tumbling for, unskeptical,
>   unsophisticated, unsuspecting, wide-eyed

My favorite is **credulous**

Answer (score 0):

They took it hook, line, and sinker.

Answer (score 0):

I recently used it this way: John 8:44 ("You are from your father the devil, and you choose to do your father's desires") has been swallowed wholesale by so many that today many dictionaries define "Pharisee" as "hypocrite." And, if not "hypocrite," many intend it as a slur meaning "charlatan" or "liar."